# ML Kit Android Studio java, how to Multible Images Text Recognition?

Tags: android, image, google-mlkit

I have a folder with about 10 images which I like to OCR extract text.
That works excellent for 1 picture, but my java skills are not good enough to implement that for multiple images.

I'm really appreciate if someone could show me a clean solution for that.

Thanks a lot
br Lukas

```
TextView output1;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);



private void OCR_list()
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/folder_with_images";
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            output1.setText(output1.getText() + ", " + files[i].getName());

            File imgFile = files[i];

            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                bitmapArray.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            } else {
                output1.setText(output1.getText()+"\n Bitmap not found!");
                return;
            }
        }

    InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmapArray.get(0), 0);
    recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Text texts) {
                            processTextRecognitionResult(texts);
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
```

Edit:

I solved it now this way, but looks awful:

```
private void new_Recognition(InputImage image) {

    recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Text texts) {
                            processTextRecognitionResult(texts);
                            bitmapArray.remove(0);
                            if (!bitmapArray.isEmpty()) {
                                InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmapArray.get(0), 0);
                                new_Recognition(image);
                            }

                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
}
```

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on inputs directly, and recognition tasks will be queued up and then processed in order internally.

```
for (Bitmap input : inputs) {
  recognizer.process(input)
      .addOnSuccessListener(text -> ...)
}
```